# how to pass my_dict to redirect, like redirect('home',my_dict)

Tags: python, html, django, web, backend

I want to pass this error into the template, but it is not working,

```
def addcomment(request):
name = request.POST['name']
comment = request.POST['comment']
if name=="" and comment=="":
    my_dict = {'error':'blank fields not allowed'}

    return redirect('home',my_dict)

Comment(name = request.POST['name'],comment = request.POST['comment']).save()
return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Comment: A redirect makes the browser make another request to another view. That could be handled by a different server. To pass messages across multiple requests, use the [django messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/messages/).

Comment: yes its working :), its there is a way to delete messages after adding into message?

Answer (score 0):

There's some examples in docs:

By passing the name of a view and optionally some positional or keyword arguments; the URL will be reverse resolved using the reverse() method:

```
def my_view(request):
   ...
   return redirect('some-view-name', foo='bar')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#examples